# How to get char from KeyCode on KeyPress for OEM?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an NumericTextBox component that extends an TextBox in my WinForms application. To filter the characters that is inputed on the textbox I overrided the OnKeyPress method and check for the numeric KeyCodes from Keys enum.

This is working great.

My problem is to extend more this NumericTextBox, so I created a CurrencyTextBox and put in that coe for formattings and etc...

My solution to make my NumericTextBox extendable was to create a Method with an char array for the accepted chars for this textbox that is not numbers. So in my OnKeyPress Method I iterate on my char array to check if the key pressed is inside and permit this key.

My problem is that in my NumericTextBox since I let only numbers to be typed I can't type commas and periods, in the KeyPress the code has the OEMComma and OEMPeriod that are not the same codes from the chars (',', '.').

My code that checks for the accepted chars looks like this:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
...
    var acceptedChars = false;
    // AcceptedChars is a String Property with all chars that this textBox should accept
    foreach (var acceptedChar in AcceptedChars.ToCharArray())
    {
        if (acceptedChar == Convert.ToChar(e.KeyCode))
        {
            acceptedChars = true;
            break;
        }
    }
...
}
```

When I hit the comma the KeyCode comes with 188 that is the OEMComma, the Convert.ToChar() function convert it to '1/4'.

PS: I'm not using the OnKeyPress event because I want to prevent the typing and not correct what was typed.

Comment: Have you tried `((char)e.KeyValue)` ?

Comment: Yes, (char)e.KeyValue is the same to Convert.ToChar()

Comment: But I said `KeyValue` not `KeyCode`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, but I've tested with KeyValue and KeyCode, all the same behavior.
The solution from b0rg resolved for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tis worked for me:

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyPress(e);
    if (false == Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != ',' && e.KeyChar != '.') e.Handled = true;
}
```

the magic is setting e.Handled = true, that way character never gets to textbox

Comment: OnKeyPress is not the problem, I want to do this on the OnKeyDown to prevent the character to be shown on the textbox.

Comment: b0rg, you're right!!
I've put the code in OnKeyPress and it worked.
The only thing that I need to do is to make a global variable for my component that the OnKeyDown set warning that the key was not parsed, and in OnKeyPress I check for the AcceptedChars and if either of them is false I make the Handled to true.
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: leave OnKeyDown alone :) on regional keyboards (Russian for one), the "." character is on "?" US key. Go figure what OEM code that one is...

Comment: Actually all my code inside OnKeyDown is based on the Keys enumerator, so it is OK, I just need to make this specific caracters that I don't know previously.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
...
    var acceptedChars = false;
    // AcceptedChars is a String Property with all chars that this textBox should accept

    KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();
    string keyChar = kc.ConvertToString(e.KeyData);

    foreach (var acceptedChar in AcceptedChars.ToCharArray())
    {
        if (acceptedChar == Convert.ToChar(keyChar))
        {
            acceptedChars = true;
            break;
        }
    }
...
}
```